# woocommerce-quick-view not working

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i have purchased this plugin(http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-quick-view/) and i have twenty twelve theme installed in my wordpress website. but product is not showing in popup like this plugin should do.

http://formallyinvited.net/product-category/after-party-admission/

this is my website. here if you will click on product quick view it should open in popup but it is not opening.

and PS i updated my wordpress version today to 3.8.1 version.
so if this is the issue then help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i deleted twenty twelve theme and from FTP uploaded new theme from wordpress. so after that everything is working fine.

so i guess it was godaddy issue.
this website was created first with installer of wordpress in godaddy and they must have some error in their theme.

now its working fine.